# Cannot import anything from within intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I just updated intellij Idea and now I cannot import anything at all. I get cannot import from "path" and the program refuses to import existing sources.

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. If it doesn't help, submit a ticket to support with the logs (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) and a screenshot of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post a ticket to jetbrains.com also the feature only supports importing directories; I was trying to import a file.